# Why do older planes not have a middle hand luggage compartment?

Tags: airliner, aviation-history, cabin-design

1. Why do older planes not have a middle hand luggage compartment?
2. Where are the oxygen masks for the people in the middle rows?

L-1011 Interior:
[image: L-1011 Interior]
777 Interior:
[image: 777 interior]

Comment: People back then had less crap they brought along

Comment: I would guess that there may also have been a bit more concern about MTOM on an L-1011 than a 777. i.e., less spare thrust, so less luggage allowed on.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Since the L-1011 was born **prior** to airlines charging for checked baggage, and passengers didn’t feel the need to bring massive carry-on items with them, the L-1011 featured compact overhead bins that were (to quote advertising of the day) “sized for a lady’s wig box.”

Source: [airlinereporter.com](http://www.airlinereporter.com/2015/09/requiem-trijet-masterpiece-lockheed-l-1011-tristar/)

The link provides really good information on the L-1011.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

There are two methods of doing the oxygen masks:

- The well known **ceiling installation**.
- A lesser-known **seatback installation**.

[image]

*A [safety card](https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/88/ac/75/88ac75606ad371d36dac11b5b5e3e236.jpg) off an Ilyushin Il-86.*

Searching for the relevant safety cards such as the one above should give you an idea which one was applicable.

Comment: I don't think this attempts to answer the question; it would make a better comment as the information is interesting and useful.

Comment: @JonathanWalters It does answer part of the question, where the O2 masks are located when not in the overhead.